# Required checkboxes in css

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a form with checkboxes list and at least one of the checkboxes should be checked.  I want to add css style that transform the checkbox border to red when nothing is checked. This my TS component:

```
policyForm = new FormGroup({
 policyNumber : new FormControl('', Validators.required),
 damageNumber : new FormControl('', Validators.required),
 coverages :new FormArray([], this.minSelectedCheckboxes(1)),
 coveragesValue:new FormArray([]),
 policyConditions : new FormControl('')
 })
  minSelectedCheckboxes(min) {
    const validator: ValidatorFn = (formArray: FormArray) => {
    const totalSelected = formArray.controls
     .map(control => control.value)
     .reduce((prev, next) => next ? prev + next : prev, 0);
     return totalSelected >= min ? null : { required: true };
    };
     return validator;
    }
```

HTML :

```
 <div class="checkbox"  ><input type = "checkbox" ></div>
```

CSS :

```
input[type="checkbox"]:required:invalid + label::before {
padding-right: 0.2em;
font-size: 1.6em;
color: red;
 }
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide a working code example as a starting point, for example an Angular project in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/). It's then way easier to help you. Read more about it https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: try this selector `input[type="checkbox"].ng-invalid + label::before`. angular uses its own classes to mark element as invalid/touched/dirty/... .